# Precision float number

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I use omnetpp-4.6 and veins-4a2 to execute my simulation.

I run this code which the variable "ch" corresponds to an id packet. In this example, 46.100 is the packet number 100 for the node 46 in my simulation.

I need to convert it to a float number, I used this method but it gives as result after converting it 46.1 and not 46.100. In my work 46.1 and 46.100 are two different packets.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::string ch = "46.100";

  std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
  std::cout.precision(3);

  float var = atof(ch.c_str());
  EV <<"The value of var is: " <<  var << "\n";

}
```

I displayed all messages in my log file with EV. So, when I use **std::cout** it displays 46.100 but when I use **EV** it displays 46.1.

There is a method to convert the float number and have the correct number that I would using EV please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: 1st don't use floating point for this; 2nd think about it mathematically `46.1 == 46.100`

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something - what's `EV`?

Comment: Also, @RichardCritten - your link and your second comment are irrelevant to the OP's question. I'm pretty sure OP understands why it's 46.1 instead of 46.100 - they're asking how to set fixed point float formatting in another stream.

Comment: EV can be used instead of ev  to make logging more efficient in omnet++, you can see this link: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp4/api/group__Envir.html

Comment: Well you don't include any Omnet++ header file, so you haven't really created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you need node 46, packet 100 to be different from node 46, packet 1, then `46.100` is fine for the first one but the second needs to be `46.001`.  If you never have more than 999 packets on a node.  If you can have more, use additional leading zeros such as `46.00100` and `46.00001`

Comment: Other comments have addressed why using a single variable or a floating point variable for this is a bad idea. Addressing only the question of how to reconfigure the formatting of EV: this is possible using an `#include <iomanip>` and calling `EV << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);` before outputting floating point values.